# zError function call in zLib impacting performance

Tags: ios, performance, instruments, zlib

When using zlib 1.25 in an iOS project, I've noticed in my profiler (Instruments) that the function zError is being called repeatedly, and is occupying 50% of the overall inflate time.

Does anyone know why zError would be getting invoked like this? I don't call it anywhere in my own code, which is a pretty boilerplate inflate function, pasted below:

```
int UPNExtractorGZInflate(const void *src, int srcLen, void *dst, int dstLen) {
    z_stream strm  = {0};
    strm.total_in  = strm.avail_in  = srcLen;
    strm.total_out = strm.avail_out = dstLen;
    strm.next_in   = (Bytef *) src;
    strm.next_out  = (Bytef *) dst;

    strm.zalloc = Z_NULL;
    strm.zfree  = Z_NULL;
    strm.opaque = Z_NULL;

    int err = -1;
    int ret = -1;

    err = inflateInit2(&strm, (15 + 16)); //15 window bits, and the +16 tells zlib to decode gzip
    if (err == Z_OK) {
        err = inflate(&strm, Z_FINISH);
        if (err == Z_STREAM_END) {
            ret = strm.total_out;
        }
        else {
             inflateEnd(&strm);
             return err;
        }
    }
    else {
        inflateEnd(&strm);
        return err;
    }

    inflateEnd(&strm);
    return ret;
}
```

And here is the relevant profiler output (notice zError taking 50% of the overall inflate time):

[image: Profiler output]

Answer (score 1):

zError isn't called by any zlib function.  If you're not calling it, then your profiler is misidentifying the function taking that time.